# Who defined $A\to B$ that yields false whenever $A$ is true and $B$ is false and why was it defined that way?

Tags: mathematical-logic

In logic we are taught the following definition.

$$A\to B$$

that yields false whenever $A$ is true **and** $B$ is false.

Who defined this and why was it defined that way? What inspired him/her?

Comment: Think about what it would mean for $A \Rightarrow B$ to be *false*: you want $A$ to be true and $B$ not to be true. That is, $A \Rightarrow B$ being false should be *the same* as “$A$ and not B” being true.  So $A \Rightarrow B$ being true should be the same as “$A$ and not $B$” being false, which is the same as its negation “(not $A$) or $B$“ being true.  In other words, $A \Rightarrow B$ should have the same truth value as “(not $A$) or $B$”, which is another way of saying these statements should be equivalent.

Comment: Hi, given both the lack of a worldwide standard for symbology in quantificational logic *and* the vagaries of HTML representation, please consider either providing a translation or replacing the symbols with their text (words) equivalent.

Comment: I agree with @KCd  that this is not a "definition" but rather a logical conclusion reached based on definition of set theory.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft:  I am trying to mitigate the confusion what I want to ask. I have no idea about the symbol. I am using the symbol that I learnt when I was in high school.

Comment: I think the most "fun" bit in the collection of  truth tables is the rule that  the statement $A \rightarrow B$ is "truth-functionally true" whenever $A$ is FALSE regardless of the value of $B$

Comment: @conifold: Thank for the link!